# Криптографические модули для js

Tags: javascript, node.js, криптография

Задача заключается в создании аутенфикации пользователя с использованием сессионного ключа. Действия следующие:
на сервере есть открытый ключ пользователя, генерируется сессионный ключ, кодируется открытым ключом пользователя, отправляется на клиент, клиент декодирует приватным ключом сессионный и уже им кодирует свой, например, логин, отправляет на сервер, где логин сравнивается с имеющимся в бд, соответственно, если получается расшифровать данные, значит приватный был правильным, значит пользователь авторизовался.

На данный момент начал использовать на клиенте [openCrypto](https://github.com/safebash/opencrypto), так как есть интересные функции (getSharedKey, encrypt, decrypt), необходимые для данного вопроса. Но для сервера он не предназначен. Можно использовать встроенную библиотеку 'crypto', но я не могу понять каким образом они создают этот самы sharedKey и как им кодируют/декодируют.

Вопроса два: Подскажите с модулем, который может удовлетворить решению задачи, или может вообще другой подход использовать?

Comment: Есть довольно малоизвестный механизм -- аутентификация **клиентскими** сертификатами в HTTPS (не путать с серверными, которые для HTTPS *необходимы*; клиентские же необязательны). Реализована внутри популярных браузеров, производится на этапе "рукопожатия SSL/TLS"; а с серверной стороны есть тот же nginx.

Comment: @D-side Это когда генерится сертификат и ключ самим сервером?

Comment: Нет, центром сертификации (CA, certificate authority), где бы он ни размещался. То сертификаты. Ключ может сгенерировать хоть сам клиент.

Comment: попробуйте bcrypt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На счет сессионного ключа пока что не разбирался, но нашел способ устроить аутентификацию и на сервере и на клиенте с помощью одного RSA модуля через открытые/закрытые ключи. 
На клиенте и на сервере я использую [node-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa), только на клиенте я его сначала билжу через [browserify](http://browserify.org). 
Если нужен будет пример кода - пишите.